# Display image using shiny in python

Tags: python, py-shiny

I want to display an image using Shiny in Python, but I cannot find an error in the code. The file is not uploaded once I open the app and input the image.

Here is the code:

```
from pathlib import Path
from shiny import render
from shiny.express import input, ui
from shiny import App, Inputs, Outputs, Session, reactive, render, ui
from shiny.types import FileInfo

ui.page_fluid(
    ui.input_file("file_input", "Upload Image"),  # Add file input
    ui.output_image("image")  
)

@render.image  
def image():
    img = {"src": input.file_input(), "width": "100px"}  
    return img
```

That I can display the image.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing some stuff, like initializing the shiny App, defining properly the layout of the page and some minor syntax issues.

Try this:

```
from shiny import App, render, ui
from shiny.types import FileInfo

app = App()

@app.page_fluid
def page():
    input_file = ui.input_file("file_input", "Upload Image")
    output_image = ui.output_image("image")

    return [input_file, output_image]

@app.render.image
def render_image():
    img_src = input.file_input()
    img_width = "100px"
    return {"src": img_src, "width": img_width}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```